# bigtable options when creating bigquery table from external bigtable data source

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

From the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-bigtable), I was able to create an external table in bigquery that points to bigtable with the following:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mydataset.BigtableTable
OPTIONS (
  format = 'CLOUD_BIGTABLE',
  uris = ['https://googleapis.com/bigtable/projects/myproject/instances/myBigtableInstance/tables/table1'],
  bigtable_options =
    """
    {
      bigtableColumnFamilies: [
        {
          "familyId": "familyId1",
          "type": "INTEGER",
          "encoding": "BINARY"
        }
      ],
      readRowkeyAsString: true
    }
    """
);
```

Is it possible to terraform this? If so, what would that look like? From the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/bigquery_table) I cannot see any way to specify bigtable options (I definitely need, at a minimum, to be able to specify `readRowkeyAsString: true`)

Comment: Could it be in the `external_data_configuration` block?

Comment: that would be where I would expect, but I don't see `bigtable_options` listed there in the tf docs

Comment: It says [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Bigquery_1_1v2_1_1Data_1_1BigtableOptions.html) that it belongs under bigtableOptions, but it doesn't work for me.